# Is my code thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

In my java application, I have a string (`MySingleton.getInstance().myString`) which gets updated based on user actions. In this application, there is a TCP server which sends the value of this string to all connected clients whenever the value of the string changes.

Each client socket gets its own thread. Here is the thread code.

```
    public void run() {
        try {
            PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(hostThreadSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            while (true) {
                synchronized (MySingleton.getInstance()) {
                 printStream.println(MySingleton.getInstance().myString);
                    try {
                        MySingleton.getInstance().wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And here is the code which writes to `MySingleton.getInstance().myString`.

```
    public void updateString(String newString) {
        synchronized (MySingleton.getInstance()) {
            MySingleton.getInstance().myString = newString;
            MySingleton.getInstance().notifyAll();
        }
    }
```

I am not familiar with synchronization in java so I am not much confident about my code. Can anybody notice anything wrong?

Comment: Has a stress test (where presumably several threads would be trying to access the variable) produced any strange results for the string?

Comment: Stress testing will only prove the presence of bugs, not the absence of bugs.  In this case, detailed examination of the code is required.

Comment: Forgot doing synchronisation/locking yourself. As you are just getting and setting on one value just us an atomic reference https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html

Comment: @StephenC Yes, I absolutely agree, I should have elaborated more clearly. I was simply stating that if the testing would have produced a strange result, that would have been a clear indication of a race condition. But yes, bugs do hide quite subtly sometimes =)

Comment: You haven't shown us enough of your code. Where is `hostThreadSocket` declared?  What does MySingleton.getInstance() look like?

Comment: I'm trying to guess what this code is supposed to do.  Is it meant to broadcast messages to multiple clients?  If so, what prevents the producer thread from calling updateString() two or more times before all of the client threads have a chance to respond to the first call?

Also, what will ever break the client threads out of that `while(true)` loop?

Comment: @jameslarge It is sufficient for clients to have the latest value of string. It is ok to miss some values if string gets updated in high frequency. Originally I expected to exit  `while(true)` loop if peer gets disconnected. But I couldn't find a way to identify when the client gets disconnected. According to my research, loop should break with an IOException when client gets disconnected and when trying to write to the disconnected socket.

Comment: I was wrong about wait() and notify() being misused here.  You are not using them the way they were _intended_ to be used, but you seem to be using them in a way that will meet your needs.  A mistake that newbies often make is called the _lost notification problem_;  That's where one thread can notify() some object before another thread calls wait(), and the second thread ends up waiting forever.  In your case, you have stated that it doesn't matter if some messages are missed, and apparently, if a thread misses one message, there will always be another, so the consumers are never truly hung..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be fine, provided that `MySingleton.getInstance()` always returns the same object.

If the method call returns different objects at different points in time, then you may get exceptions due to synchronizing on one instance, and then calling wait or notify on a different instance.  In addition, there may be memory hazards because you are not synchronizing on the object that you are accessing / updating.

Comment: _...provided that MySingleton.getInstance() always returns the same object._  That's a big assumption, and safely constructing a singleton object in a multi-threaded environment is something that countless newbies have screwed up in the past.  Also, I don't see how you can pronounce this thread-safe if you don't know where `hostThreadSocket` is declared, and you haven't even touched on how this program fragment mis-uses `wait()` and `notifyAll()`.

Comment: *"That's a big assumption"* - Precisely.  And that is why I 1) call it out and 2) state what happens if the assumption is not correct.  (See the 2nd paragraph.)

Comment: @jameslarge can you please mention how `wait()` and `notifyAll()` is misused here?